# Compare values in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a cricket application for Android.

How do i compare two values in a while loop? For setting notification, I have stored scores into an array list and also the same score in to another array list. In a while loop, I need to compare if there is a change in the wickets value.

All values come from a database. My code is below:

```
public void checkNotfifications(){
        ListIterator<Score> litr = scoreList.listIterator();
        ls = s;
        while (litr.hasNext()) {
            Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "s.getInnings() = "+Integer.parseInt(s.getInnings()));
            Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "ls.getInnings() = "+Integer.parseInt(ls.getInnings()));
            Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Checking for i notifications..."+Integer.parseInt(s.getInnings())+" 2nd "+Integer.parseInt(ls.getInnings()));
            if(Integer.parseInt(s.getInnings()) == Integer.parseInt(ls.getInnings())){
                Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Checking for  w notifications..."+Integer.parseInt(s.getWickets())+" A "+Integer.parseInt(ls.getWickets()));
                if ( Integer.parseInt(s.getWickets()) > Integer.parseInt(ls.getWickets())) {
                    showNotification("A wicket down");
                }
            }
    /*      if (Integer.parseInt(s.getInnings()) >= Integer.parseInt(ls.getInnings())) {
                ls = s;
            }
    */
            s = litr.next();
            ls = litr.next();


}
}
```

Comment: You compare two values by using comparison operators.  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: This really has little to do with android, it's a java question.

Comment: This has something to do  with [cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket) i reckon. If someone knows how its played they may be able to understand OP's confusing question.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity to the best of my ability, however I'm having trouble figuring out (thus articulating) your exact question. Please consider adding a sentence or paragraph below your code sample to explain _exactly_ where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to detect the fall of a wicket during a match?

Is the score list made up of runs for each stroke?

Does getInnings return the current run total?

It looks like you're trying to do: if the score hasn't changed from one stroke to the next check whether a wicket has fallen. If so post a notification.

Are you sure that s and ls contain different things. You appear to be setting them equal at the start.

This is all conjecture on my part as you don't seem to have given us enough information. Are you sure it's your method of comparison inside the while loop which is at fault and not your mental model of the problem?